# php if $_SERVER SCRIPT_NAME and REQUEST_URI seeing files with query strings as different files

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I'm using a few variations of php if statements to parse content based on what file is being requested, such as `/index.php` (I'm using nginx and php-fpm)

```
<?php if (preg_match('#^/(articles/|index\.php|$)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1): ?>

<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.php'): ?>
```

Simply put, it's working unless a request is based with a query string, such as `/index.php?135897`. When this occurs, it no longer sees the file as being `index.php`, and so it does not properly parse the content.

How can I get these if statements to count query strings as being the same file?

Comment: You are looking for `strpos`. Check if it is not false (`!==`).

Comment: Did you try using .htaccess file to route your requests?

Comment: @Vaishak I'm using nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php)

```
$scriptName = parse_url($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], PHP_URL_PATH);

<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.php'): ?>
```